# Check when a process finishes in java?

Tags: java, file-upload, process, upload

How to check when a particular process has been finished? In my scenario download, process, upload is happening sequentially.

Below is what I'm trying to accomplish -

1) Downloading an excel file from a server (Size varies - which is the reason I'm trying to check time)

```
call S3DataGetUrlForDownload( parameters )
```

2) Process the excel file inside java servlet, upload it to an API (which is different from the first server).

```
upload.fileUpload( parameters );
```

Never programmed with the threads/timers. Added this part of sleep code, but when excel is big it fails.

```
 try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
 } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
 }
```

Comment: You say "download, process, upload is happening sequentially." Do you mean concurrently? If you're doing it in another thread you can use `thread.join()` to wait for the thread to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the thread class there is a method named join that will block until that thread completes execution. Just call that for your download/worker thread (from main thread) and it will behave the same as if you called Thread.sleep with exactly the right time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it in another thread, *don't* do it in another thread. Then 'process completion' basically becomes 'the called method returns'.